# Add upload scope for vimeo API in https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize will always return error

Tags: api, oauth, upload, scope, vimeo

I try the vimeo oauth first step, get the authrization code, below is the browser url:
https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=*************&redirect_uri=************&scope=public+private+upload&state=**********
I set the scope is public private upload.
Then the web page always report me error:
An error has occurred. You won't be able to connect to Vimeo until it is fixed by the developer.
Dear app owner, we are unable to generate access tokens using one or more of the scopes you provided.

Comment: Is anyone encounter same issue? Cloud you please give me any suggestion?  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I use this and it works correctly:
`https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=********&redirect_uri= http%3A%2F%2Fintrepidis.blogspot.co.uk%2F&scope=public%20edit%20upload&state=****`

Just make sure the redirect_uri exactly matches (apart from url encoding) the `Your Callback URLs` section on the Vimeo developer page for your app.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I retry it again, it does not work yet. But if I didn't provide any scope, I have got an access token. But I upload a file using this token, I got the error below: Your access token does not have the \"upload\" scope.

Comment: Maybe your encoding is wrong, you should check the request that you're sending with a tool such as `Fiddler2`.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I set  the scope is public and edit, it works correctly. The URL is:https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=***&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth.dmc.cn%2Foauth%2Frest%2Fvimeo&scope=public%20edit&state=*
                         But if I set the scope is public, edit and upload. 
Then the web page reports me error: Please contact the app owner and let him or her know that ****** was unable to create an oauth2 authorization code because the scope is invalid.
So I think the encoding must be correct.  But I don’t know why I can’t use upload scope.

Comment: In the Vimeo Developer "My Apps" page (where your Client Secret etc is) you must register your app for upload access.

Comment: I checked "My Apps" page. My app is approved for uploading for PRO accounts, but my account is a Basic account. Is your account a PRO account or Basic account?  If I am is a Basic account, may I apply for upload access for Basic accounts?

Comment: My personal account is Vimeo Plus. My understanding is that even basic accounts should work, as long as you have enough remaining quota for the size of the video you want to upload. Maybe check how much quota you have left this month?

Comment: Thank you very much. I confirmed with vimeo. My app is approved for uploading for PRO accounts. So I must use PRO accounts. Maybe I need to apply for another app for basic account.